# UIPickerView is getting disappear on updating label in didSelectRow method in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am facing an issue in UIPickerView iOS 8. My pickerView is getting disappeared when I select and update value from picker to UILabel in didSelectRow method. This is working fine in iOS 7.

//Add Picker in ViewWillAppear

```
locationPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, locationView.frame.size.width, 90)];
    locationPickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    locationPickerView.dataSource = self;
    locationPickerView.delegate = self;
    activityIndicatorView.center = locationPickerView.center;
    [locationView addSubview:locationPickerView];
```

Here locationView is UIView which is added in xib.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

       cityNameLabel.text = [cityNameArray objectAtIndex:row];

        thePickerView.hidden = YES;

    }
```

if I comment following line picker is not disappearing. But I have to update label :(

```
 cityNameLabel.text = [cityNameArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: I have added picker view into locationView(added via xib) which is UIView class.I gave you relevant code

Answer (score 0):

you are hiding picker view in didSelectRow code. It may be the problem.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

   cityNameLabel.text = [cityNameArray objectAtIndex:row];

 //   thePickerView.hidden = YES;

}
```

comment  thePickerView.hidden = YES; and check.

Comment: Provide me your implementation of locationView

Comment: [locationPickerView reloadAllComponents];comment once.I think some where it is hiding or recreating or deleting

Comment: from where i have added it multiple time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63786/discussion-between-007-and-helpmetohelpyou).